# Xunit.runner.visualstudio is adding dlls to nuget package Content folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Short question:
When I add a dependency to XUnit.Runner.VisualStudio to a project that generates a Nuget package with a Content folder, it adds three dlls to the Content folder of the generated Nuget package. Why is this, and how can I stop it?

Background:
So I have a nuget package we use to set up test projects for our company. I combines various internal and external tools and dependencies so that setting up new test projects only involves installing a single nuget package.

Recently I've been updating it to use XUnit 2.0.0.

Seeing that the newer XUnit templates reference XUnit.Runner.VisualStudio, I referenced it as well. Once I did that I noticed that the generated Nuget package had 3 dlls added to the Content folder:

- xunit.abstractions.dll
- xunit.runner.utility.desktop
- xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll

Here is the only portion of the nuspec file outside of the meta-data:

```
<files>
    <file src="Content\AutoDataAttribute.cs.pp" target="content" />
</files>
```

If I remove this line so that no content folder is generated the dlls are not added.

I build the package using this command:

```
nuget pack $projectFile -Build -Symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory $projectPath\bin\Release
```

I'm stumped on this one. Why would xunit.visualstudio.runners add dlls to the content folder? Why would it only do it when I'm generating a content folder and adding a file to it with an explicit reference?

Comment: Are you referencing the test nuget package from your main project ? Or a separate project ? You `nuget pack` command points to the sln or the csproj ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I have a utilities solution, and within it is the TestFramework project. The TestFramework project has all the nuget dependencies installed that we want a final test project to have (xunit, autofixture, fluentAssertsions, etc.) The project also has a TestFramework.nuspec file. I then package and publish the package generated.

In other solutions, whenever we need to set up a new testing project we just install the testFramework package into the test project. It imports all of the nuget dependencies and adds any config files necessary.

Comment: Oh! You're trying to build the nuget for your test framework! I thought you were trying to build another project using it! Sorry.